# Checking for href attribute of a hovered link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of links with background images with a particular class.

```
a(href="some-url" style="background-image: image-url").location-thumb
```

I am using Jquery hover function to check which link has been hovered upon & accordingly want to change background in an adjoining column.
I particularly need to check href attribute of the link.

I need the syntax in if loop format like below:

```
if(hovered link attribute = "www.google.com"){
      //proceed further
}
```

Comment: Hey there, please post the code you have written so far in relation to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for your replies. Finally implemented the code, where on & off hover over an image with a link, different google maps are set to an iframe element.

```
  $('a.location-thumb').hover(function(){  
    if($(this).attr("href") == "/2013/01/20/30-shali-tibba.html"){
      document.getElementById('iframe1').src = "https://www.google.com
      /maps/embed1"
    }
  }, function(){
      document.getElementById('iframe1').src = "https://www.google.com
      /maps/embed2"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href="#hover"]').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature")')
    }, function () {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports")')
    }
  )
})
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports') no-repeat center;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#hover">Hover Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can listen when the user hovers an anchor with a given class and check whether its href attribute matches a desired or desired URLs and perform arbitrary logic if so. Here are three different samples. The first checks whether the anchor is pointing to a specific URL. The second checks whether the link has a certain string in it and the third checks if the link matches a set of URLs in an array.

```
    //option 1 -the hovered link is an exact match to a string

      $("a.location-thumb").hover(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("href") === "http://www.google.com") {
        alert("Yes")
        //add whatever
        $("#some-id").css("background-color", "crimson");
      }
      }, function() {
    $("#some-id").css("background-color", "orange");
  /*this is called when the user stops hovering*/});
        //option 2:  the hovered link includes a particular keywords in it

        $("a.location-thumb").hover(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("google.com") !== -1) {
        alert("Yes")

        }

        }, function() {/*mouseleave*/});

        //Option 3: the hovered link points to one of several websites
        var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://facebook.com'];
        $("a.location-thumb").hover(function() {
        if (urls.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) !== -1) {
        alert("Yes")

        }

        }, function() {/*mouseleave*/});
```

With Vanilla JavaScript you can do something like this:

```
      var specialAnchors = document.getElementsByClassName("location-thumb");
      for (var i = 0; i < specialAnchors.length;i++ ) {
        specialAnchors[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
          var href = this.getAttribute("href");
          console.log("hi");
          console.log(href);
          if (href === "http://www.google.com") {
            alert ("Yes");
          }
        })

        specialAnchors[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
          alert("Mouse left this place");
        })
      }
```